# Wordpress have user website url appear in div

Tags: php, wordpress, key

I am trying to place a Wordpress user website URL into a div on a page. Here is my code. I appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks.

```
<div>
 <?php 
  $user_id = 4;
  $key = 'user_url';
  $single = true;
  $user_website = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user-url', $single ); 
  echo '<p>' . $user_website . '</p>'; 
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kirk. I guess I overlooked that. I read through the documentation again.

Comment: I have this code so far, and it does pull in the user website (from the user's profile) but, unfortunately, it's not a clickable link. It's only text.

<?php $user_info = get_userdata(4);
                        echo '<"a href">' .$user_info->user_url . '</a>';
?>

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```
<div>
<?php 
 $user_id = 4;
 $key = 'user_url';
 $single = true;
 $user_website = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
 if( !empty($user_website) ) {
   echo '<p><a href="'.$user_website.'">'.$user_website.'</a></p>'; 
 }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately, it's not working for me.